# Does SQL server support an in-built mechanism to copy a row to a log or history table when it is updated?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Is there an in-built mechanism that copies a row to a log or another table when it is updated. Or is the only option to write a custom trigger on update.

Comment: You mean like [Temporal Table History](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4674/managing-temporal-table-history-in-sql-server-2016/)?

Comment: A temporal table would do, though i dont need the temporal history. I wont ever query what did this record look like at a point in time. I'm just looking for an audit trail of changes.

Comment: Other options are [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) (managed instances only) and [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)...

Comment: This two article by Ameena might help. [https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5211/sql-server-temporal-tables-vs-change-data-capture-vs-change-tracking--part-1/](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5211/sql-server-temporal-tables-vs-change-data-capture-vs-change-tracking--part-1/) and [SQL Server Temporal Tables vs Change Data Capture vs Change Tracking - part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5212/sql-server-temporal-tables-vs-change-data-capture-vs-change-tracking--part-2/).

Comment: Just a note that none of the following options will tell you who did the modification: temporal, change tracking, change data capture. If you want to know who did it, then you have triggers and Server Audit. The latter has issues with parameterized SQL so make sure you do a POC early.